# How can I prepare my image dataset for a federated model?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, tensorflow-federated

How could I transform my dataset (composed of images) in a federated dataset?
I am trying to create something similar to emnist but for my own dataset.

> tff.simulation.datasets.emnist.load_data(
> only_digits=True, cache_dir=None )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to create the clientData object first

for example:

```
client_data = tff.simulation.datasets.ClientData.from_clients_and_tf_fn(client_ids,
create_dataset)
```

where create_dataset is a serializable function but first you have to prepare your images [read this tutorial about preprocessing data](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data#decoding_image_data_and_resizing_it)

```
labels_tf = tf.convert_to_tensor(labels) 

def parse_image(filename):

parts = tf.strings.split(filename, os.sep)
label_str = parts[-2]

label_int = tf.where(labels_tf == label_str)[0][0]
image = tf.io.read_file(filename)
image = tf.io.decode_jpeg(image,channels=3) 
image = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(image, tf.float32)
image = tf.image.resize(image, [32, 32]) 

return image, label_int
```

When you prepared your data pass it to the create_dataset function

```
def create_dataset(client_id):
....

list_ds = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(<path of your dataset>)

images_ds = list_ds.map(parse_image)
    
return images_ds
```

after this step, you can make some preprocessing function

```
NUM_CLIENTS = 10
NUM_EPOCHS = 5
BATCH_SIZE = 20
SHUFFLE_BUFFER = 100
PREFETCH_BUFFER = 10

def preprocess(dataset):


  return dataset.repeat(NUM_EPOCHS).shuffle(SHUFFLE_BUFFER, seed=1).batch(
      BATCH_SIZE).prefetch(PREFETCH_BUFFER)
```

After this you could make a tf.data.Dataset which will be suitable for federated training.

```
def make_federated_data(client_data, client_ids):
  return [
      preprocess(client_data.create_tf_dataset_for_client(x))
      for x in client_ids
  ]
```

After this your dataset is ready for federated learning!

Comment: And how could I implement it using ImageDataGenerator?

Answer (score 0):

Federated datasets in TFF are represented as [ClientData](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/api_docs/python/tff/simulation/datasets/ClientData) objects. There are multiple subclasses that can be used depending on your dataset.

Two potentially relevant ways to create such objects:

- Use [`ClientData.from_clients_and_tf_fn`](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/api_docs/python/tff/simulation/datasets/ClientData#from_clients_and_tf_fn). This is useful for smaller datasets.
- As a [SqlClientData](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/api_docs/python/tff/simulation/datasets/SqlClientData), which uses a SQL-file backing to improve performance. This can be done through [`tff.simulation.datasets.save_to_sql_client_data`](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/api_docs/python/tff/simulation/datasets/save_to_sql_client_data). Effectively, this allows you to do one-time work to create the client datasets and save the result, rather than having to reconstruct the datasets each time.

Note that both of these require TF-serializable functions for creating datasets from ids. If you just tensors you can use [TestClientData](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/api_docs/python/tff/simulation/datasets/TestClientData), but this is intended only for small-scale datasets.